# How do I access the multipart_params values on the server with Plupload?

Tags: javascript, plupload

I have assigned some arbitrary data to a Plupload instance's multipart_params like so:

```
multipart_params: { 'username': 'bob','id': some_value }
```

How can I access these values on my server within the upload.php script that is called when files are uploaded?

Comment: Why the down vote? The documentation on Plupload is very very sparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the $_REQUEST variable (PHP side, of course):

```
$_REQUEST['username'];
$_REQUEST['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

it's safer to check the param is not empty and use a default value if it is:

```
$username = isset($_REQUEST["username"]) ? $_REQUEST["username"] : '0';
```